# Change state of component using another component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm super new to react so pardon me if this is a stupidly simple question but I'd like to change the state of an image (the component 'Title') when the cursor hovers of the play button (the component 'playbutton').  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is the code for Title:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Title.css';


class Title extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       imgSrc: require('./dalogo')
    };
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseOver() {
    this.setState({
      imgSrc: require('./difflogo')
    });
  }

  handleMouseOut() {
    this.setState({
      imgSrc: require('./dalogo')
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='logo'>
        <img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} src={this.state.imgSrc} width = {1000} heigth = {900} alt = 'Logo'/>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

Title.propTypes = {
}

Title.defaultProps = {
}

export default Title;
```

Here's the code for PlayButton:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './PlayButton.css';
import logo2 from './difflogo';
import logo from './dalogo';
import Title from './Title';

class PlayButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           imgSrc: require('./playbutton.png')
        };
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    handleMouseOver () {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: require('./playbuttonblue.png')
        });
        this.changeState();
    }

    handleMouseOut () {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: require('./playbutton.png')
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className='playbutton'>
             <button className='buttonprop'>
              <img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} src={this.state.imgSrc} width = {100} heigth = {50} alt = 'Play'/>
              </button>
          </div>          
        );
    }
}

PlayButton.propTypes = {
}

PlayButton.defaultProps = {
}
export default PlayButton
```

Comment: You need to maintain a relationship between two components to identify whether the hovering on the image is happening or not. You can do it using the state variable. Maintain a state variable and send the update to the `Title` component from `Play`.

Comment: Related official tutorial/documentation on sharing state between components: [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: ty for your replies, but i'm confused how to create this state variables and what will be passed into it.